# Shimano BB: add grease over threadlock?

Tags: shimano, bottom-bracket, installation, threaded-bottom-bracket

The dealer manual for the Shimano BBR60 bottom bracket says to grease the threads of the cups before inserting. But I noticed that the threads have some kind of grey threadlock compound applied to them. *It seems strange* to put grease over threadlock since that would defeat the purpose of threadlock. Is that really what I'm supposed to do?

Comment: Does anyone know if that grey stuff is actually threadlock (as in, it is an adhesive), or is it just a nylon patch meant to increase thread friction via mechanical interference?

Comment: I just read a BB install article from Park Tools, which says: `New cups may come with dry threadlocker already applied. Install these as they come.` So that's one answer from a reputable source.

Answer (score 4):

Grease on the threads of both the shell and cups is necessary to prevent galling the metal as torque increases to its final setting.  The water proof quality of grease helps prevent ingress of water into the shell.  Grease facilitates removal by rust protection and keeping a barrier between possibly dissimilar metals of the bottom bracket and BB shell of the bike.

What you see on the threads of the cups should be considered a thread filler and not true liquid thread locker. The thread filler works by decreasing the clearance between threads creating a tighter fit which increases the breakaway force required to start loosening the cup. Any grease applied to the cup threads will not interfere with the intended function of the thread filler.